# Как через скрипт поменять цвет отдельного символа в TextMeshPro Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте всем читающим!
я сделал привязку клавиш обычное нажатие через Input к буквам русского алфавита всё работает ,следующий шаг - у меня есть текст меш про который я вывожу на экран и хотелось бы при нажатии кнопки менять цвет у отдельной буквы в этом тексте, нажатия уже отслеживаются всё готово ,как через скрипт менять цвет отдельного символа.

Пытался использовать index символа думал что раз тип string у текста то поможет ,но text[i].color = new color() не работает ,видимо меш про это делается как то по другому или же вообще не поддерживает.

Хотелось бы не прибегать к костылям.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/RichText.html

Answer (score 0):

У текста есть поле bool RichText, вы его можете видеть в инспекторе. Если он включён, то внутри поля text можно писать html тегами. Так можно попробовать выделять символ тегом и менять цвет. Так например можете попробовать в поле text написать:

```
a b c <h3 style="color:Tomato;">d</h3> e f ...
```